# Fetchin Content in IMAP repeating issue

Tags: imap

I am Fetching content of the mail through IMAP, but I am not able to properly Fetching content.

My flow is like.

1> Connecting to IMAP.
2> Authenticate user.
3> Retrive the No of Folder.
4> Select Folder.
5> Retrive list of UID of Selected Folder.
6> And Fetching mail content according to UID which already selected folder.

But I ma not able to fetching a proper content beacause the things is that let say I have 6 mail and I am retriving those mail UID.

And passing to one by one into the FETCH Command; but the FECTH Command is retriving one last mail content every time.

I don't know why it's happening. my FETCH Command is like this.
            byte[] commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(("$ FETCH " + UID + " (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM DATE)])" + "\r\n").ToCharArray());

Is there any solution then let me kwon..

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're passing a UID to the server, you must use `UID FETCH`, not `FETCH`:

```
byte[] commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(("$ UID FETCH " + UID + " (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM DATE)])" + "\r\n").ToCharArray());
```

Comment: Dear dkarp Thanks alot.B'coz I am phasing this issue within a weel and finally I got the solution..!!